# Apache rewrite rule to make pretty URLs

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to keep my URLs pretty.

Say we have the URL:

```
severhost.com/team/4325
```

In the team.php file I want the 4325 to be filled in `$_GET["id"]`.

I have this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?team/([0-9]+)$ team.php?id=$1 [R]
```

but this actually changes the URL in the browser to be:

```
severhost.com/team.php?id=4325
```

I want the URL in the browser to remain `severhost.com/team/4325`.

Comment: Have you tried the [L,QSA] (Last, query string append) flag?... [R] is for redirects.

Answer (score 2):

the `[R]` flag at the end of the rule means redirect. So what you are doing is telling it to redirect instead of rewrite the rule. You likely want to just change it to a `[L]`.

Comment: When I do L, the browser does a 400 Bad Request. Im beggining to think, I may have other issues with my apache setup

Comment: You could probably drop the `[L]` all together. However, it is likely there is a problem elsewhere.

Comment: I set the flag to [PS] and I seem to be getting the results I want

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule ^/?team/([0-9]+)$ team.php?id=$1 [PS]

The flag needed to be set to [PS]